# Increasing maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a facebook app. I request to facebook graph api for many times in loops.
After nearly 1 minute running I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 300

I searched a lot and as I understand this problem comes from *xdebug*, not php. So I tried 
`xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500` in **php.ini** but it does not solve my problem. Is there another way of increasing this limit?

Comment: Why do you nest functions for more than 100 levels? Highly complicated functions / just a logic bug ?

Comment: Firstly I am getting all facebook pages that user like, after that getting all posts of those pages, after that getting all users who liked those posts. Because of working with large data, I need to nest functions in high level.

Comment: 100 nested level is definitely too many. Recursive is not equal to nested pattern. Try to post your logic here.

Comment: It depend on the framework used ! Symfony for example NEED more than 100 level to run normally.

Comment: @Vins4nity Why do not select the answer of your questions after people answered them? Do you live???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php5 you need to modify `vim /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini`, if not exist, create it.
My config :

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
```